# Issue when sudo something after a hostname change

Tags: command-line, sudo, hostname

I was tired of my system's name so i decided to change it.
I `gksudo gedit /etc/hostname` and changed my first and never touched computer name to a new one.
Then now when i `sudo` something like `sudo gedit` my terminal prompts `~: unable to resolve host <my_new host_name_i_gksudo>`.

When i `sudo cat /etc/hosts` it gives me:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host <not_of_your_business!>
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   leviathan

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

How could i get rid of this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `su -` but if you didn't setup root password, boot to recovery mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you defined your new hostname in your `/etc/hosts` file?

When changing your hostname, you need to alter it in **both** the `/etc/hostname` **and** `/etc/hosts` files.  And once you've done that, either reboot or restart the hostname service:

```
sudo service hostname restart
```

Answer (score 3):

Change this line in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.1.1     your-old-hostname
```

to:

```
127.0.1.1     your-new-hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

The sudo command can take a hostname parameter.  eg.

> sudo -h my-new-hostname reboot

P.S.  After the reboot, it should all be happy assuming you've changed your hostname correctly.